# Combining ArcGIS API for JavaScript external files for faster performance?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, performance, mobile

I have a jQuery mobile application which runs 'ok' but I am looking at trying to speed up performance.

I ran the 'Audit' tool against it in Chrome's Developer Tools and one of the recommendations is to combine external javascript files

Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: If you're looking to reduce the number of files requested, I would look into the ArcGIS API for JavaScript Web Optimizer. https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/inside_web_optimizer.html

Comment: Thanks.. I saw the Optimizer yesterday and will be trying it out today..